# Node Red - node-red-contrib-whatsapp-link

Tags: whatsapp, node-red

i tried this library and it works for sending whatsapp but.. when i try to send images it breaks... and hangs node-red.

i´ve left some comments in this link: https://github.com/raweee/node-red-contrib-whatsapp-link/pull/25

which is a pull request, i tryied what the autor says and changing puppeteer options directly wont open node-red but changing to false the headless of puppeteer i can inspect if the functions that are tried to execute exists... and it doesn´t.. pictures below:
[image: functions in console]

[image: console error]

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved!! :)
a LOT of research behind the problem was related to web-whatsapp.js library....
you can see the whole conversation with the creator and one contributor in the github posted in my question.

SHORT ANSWER (change the following):
archive: node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/util/Injected.js

```
window.Store.MediaPrep = window.mR.findModule('MediaPrep')[0]; //find this line
window.Store.MediaPrep = window.mR.findModule('prepRawMedia')[0]; //replace with this
```

i take this solution from this: [solution](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/2076#issuecomment-1474049879)